# getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null) didn't notify cursor

Tags: android

i'm trying to undestand Content Provider,but i stuck in one thing,
notification of cursor didn't work,if i update cursor in query method everything works fine.Where i get wrong.Thank you! This is full source code 
https://github.com/denmariupol/StartAndroid/tree/master/lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h/src/main

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.interfaces.IUpdateCursor;
import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.fragments.Insert;
import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IUpdateCursor {
    public final static Uri PROVIDER_URI = Uri.parse("com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h");
    private Cursor cursor;
    private MyAdapter scAdapter;
    private ActivityMainBinding mainActivity;
    private OnClickListener clickListener;
    private int colId;
    private int colText;
    private ArrayList<Integer> chekedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        stethoInit();


        mainActivity = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        colId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MyProvider.ID);
        colText = cursor.getColumnIndex(MyProvider.TEXT);

        String[] from = new String[]{MyProvider.ID, MyProvider.TEXT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.itemId, R.id.itemText};

        scAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to, 0);

        mainActivity.listItem.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mainActivity.listItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final View v = view;
                final LinearLayout itemUpdateLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.itemUpdateLayout);
                final LinearLayout itemViewLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.itemViewLayout);

                TextView idView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemId);
                TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
                final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.updateTextField);
                Button updateButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.updateRecButton);
                editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        Log.d("!!!","onTextChanged -> "+s.toString());
//                        ed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });

                final String updId  = idView.getText().toString();
                updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                        String text = editText.getText().toString();

                        Log.d("!!!","clicked text -> "+editText.getText().toString());
                        if(text.length() > 0) {
                            cv.put(MyProvider.TEXT, text);
                            Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI,Long.valueOf(updId));
                            getContentResolver().update(newUri, cv,null,null);

//                            Cursor cursor = null;
//                            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//                                cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null,null);
//                            }
//                            updateCursor(cursor);
                        }


                        itemUpdateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        itemViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                editText.setText(textView.getText());

                itemUpdateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemViewLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }
        });

        mainActivity.insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment insertFragment = new Insert();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container, insertFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

        mainActivity.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chekedItems.size() > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < chekedItems.size(); i++) {
                        Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI,chekedItems.get(i));
                        getContentResolver().delete(newUri,null,null);
//                        Cursor cursor = null;
//                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null,null);
//                        }
//                        updateCursor(cursor);
                    }
                    chekedItems.clear();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Nothing selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void stethoInit() {
        // Create an InitializerBuilder
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder initializerBuilder =
                Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);

        // Enable Chrome DevTools
        initializerBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(
                Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this)
        );

        // Enable command line interface
        initializerBuilder.enableDumpapp(
                Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this)
        );

        // Use the InitializerBuilder to generate an Initializer
        Stetho.Initializer initializer = initializerBuilder.build();

        // Initialize Stetho with the Initializer
        Stetho.initialize(initializer);
    }


    @Override
    public void updateCursor(Cursor newCusor) {
        scAdapter.changeCursor(newCusor);
        scAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //hide keyboard
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }


    private class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
        private int layout;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            final String id = cursor.getString(colId);
            String title = cursor.getString(colText);
            TextView idView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemId);
            idView.setText(id);
            TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            textView.setText(title);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            checkBox.setChecked(false);

            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!chekedItems.contains(Integer.valueOf(id))){
                        chekedItems.add(Integer.valueOf(id));
                    }else{
                        chekedItems.remove(chekedItems.indexOf(Integer.valueOf(id)));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout,parent,false);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return getCount();
        }


    }
}
```

Insert Fragment

```
package com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.fragments;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.MainActivity;
import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.MyProvider;
import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.R;
import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.databinding.FragmentInsertBinding;
import com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h.interfaces.IUpdateCursor;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Insert extends Fragment{

    Activity activity;
    public Insert() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.activity = (Activity)context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FragmentInsertBinding insertBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_insert,container,false);
        View v  = insertBinding.getRoot();

        insertBinding.insertRecButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                String text = insertBinding.insertTextField.getText().toString();
                if(text.length() > 0) {
                    cv.put(MyProvider.TEXT, text);
                    getContext().getContentResolver().insert(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, cv);
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(Insert.this).commit();
                    insertBinding.insertTextField.clearFocus();

//                    Cursor cursor = null;
//                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//                        cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null,null);
//                    }
//                    ((IUpdateCursor)activity).updateCursor(cursor);
                }
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }

//    public interface IUpdateCursor{
//        void updateCursor(Cursor newCursor);
//    }
}
```

MyProvider

```
 package com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;



/**
 * Created by den on 2017-03-31.
 */

public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider{
    private final String DB_NAME = "my";
    private int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.lesson101_contentprovider_creation_h";
    private static final String PATH = "table";

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH);
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "MYTABLE";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";

    private final String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ("
            + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + TEXT + " text);";

    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static final int TABLE = 1;
    private static final int TABLE_ID = 2;

    static final String CONTACT_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd."
            + AUTHORITY + "." + PATH;

    private static UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PATH, TABLE);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, PATH + "/#", TABLE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());

        return true;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection,
                        @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case TABLE:
                sortOrder = ID;
                break;
            case TABLE_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                sortOrder = TEXT;
                break;
        }
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DB_TABLE,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
        Log.d("!!!","query -> "+uri.toString());
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),CONTENT_URI);
        return cursor;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case TABLE:

                break;
            case TABLE_ID:
                return CONTACT_CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values) {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("!!!","insert -> "+uri.toString());
        if(uriMatcher.match(uri) != TABLE)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: "+uri);

        long id = database.insert(DB_TABLE,null,values);
        Uri resultUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI,id);
        Log.d("!!!","insert after -> "+resultUri.toString());
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(resultUri,null);
        return resultUri;
    }


    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case TABLE:
                break;
            case TABLE_ID:
                String id  = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                selection = ID + " = " + id;
                break;
        }
        int c =  database.delete(DB_TABLE,selection,selectionArgs);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return c;
    }


    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs) {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
            case TABLE:
                break;
            case TABLE_ID:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                selection = ID + " = " +id;
                Log.d("!!!",id);
                break;
        }
        int c =  database.update(DB_TABLE,values,selection,null);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return c;
    }





    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            updateDB(db,0,DB_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }


        private void updateDB(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            if(oldVersion < 1)
                db.execSQL(CREATE_DB);
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the uri used in setNotificationUri is matching the ones used in the getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange()?

```
Cursor.setNotificationUri()
```

will register for the underline uri for the

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

which is called when such as at ContentProvider's insert(), update() and delete() calls, so the Cursor (has setNotificationUri()) will be notified.

If you are using CursorAdapter, by default, CursorAdapter objects will get this notification issued by getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange.

Another thing to make sure not to do cursor.close(), the close() will cause unregister the content observer which was registered by CursorLoader. And the cursor closing is managed by CursorLoader.